# Find the limit of $(4^{n}+3^{2n})^{1/n}$

Tags: analysis, limits

how would I go about finding the limit of $$(4^{n}+3^{2n})^{1/n}$$
What method would be best to use here?,
I have tried dividing through by $4^{n}$ $$(1+ \frac{3^{2n}}{4^n})^{1/n}$$ But this seems to be of no uses,
Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Try dividing through by $(3^2)^n$.

Comment: So then I get $3^{2}(\frac{4^{n}}{3^{2n}})^{1/n}$ which gives a limit of $3^{2}$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419882/prove-the-following-limit-lim-n-to-infty-3n-4n1-n-4

Comment: Non-rigorously, as $n \to \infty,$ $9^n$ dominates over $4^n$, so the limit is equivalent to $(9^n)^{1/n} = 9$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can squeeze it:

$$3^2 = (3^{2n})^{1/n} < (4^n+3^{2n})^{1/n} < (3^{2n} + 3^{2n})^{1/n} = 2^{1/n}\cdot 3^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

if we say $(4^n+9^n)^{1/n}=t$ and take logarithm of both sides then we have $\frac{\ln(4^n+9^n)}{n}=\ln t$. Take the limit of left side and use L' hospitale rule then you have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(4^n+9^n)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4^n.\ln 4+9^n.\ln 9}{4^n+9^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{9^n\left((4/9)^n\ln 4+\ln 9\right)}{9^n\left((4/9)^n +1\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(4/9)^n\ln 4+\ln 9}{(4/9)^n +1}=\ln 9.$$ So you get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln t=\ln 9$, which means that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}t=9.$