# How to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n + 3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to compute the limit of a sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n + 3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ to obtain the result? The answer is $3$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419882/prove-the-following-limit-lim-n-to-infty-3n-4n1-n-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $(2^n+3^n)^{1/n} =  \left(3^n \cdot \left((\tfrac{2}{3})^n+1\right)\right)^{1/n} = 3\left((\tfrac{2}{3})^n+1\right)^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$3^n\leq(2^n+3^n)\leq(3^{n}+3^{n})=2\times3^n$$
$$3\leq(2^n+3^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq2^{\frac{1}{n}}3$$
$$\text{Now use the Squeeze Theorem}$$

Comment: I like this answer cause it is easily modifyable to work with more than two summands.