# Limit of $(\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I assume it is $1$. 
Though $1$ is a limit of the function  $(\frac{2^x+3^x+4^x}{5^x+6^x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Besides, even if it is $1$, I still need to solve the following inequality

$|(\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}-1|< \epsilon$

for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. That I don't know how to do as well.

Comment: Why do you assume it is 1?
You can clearly show that is is smaller than $\lim \left(\frac{3\cdot 4^n}{2\cdot 5^n}\right)^{1/n}$, which is 4/5. While this is not the final answer it can help you to get there.

Comment: @Jxt921 See my approach below. More classical and less tricks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that 
$$(\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \geq (\frac{4^n}{2 \cdot 6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{2}{3}\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
While
$$(\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq (\frac{3 \cdot 4^n}{6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 3^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
And
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} 3^{\frac{1}{n}}=1.$$

So the answer is $\frac{2}{3}$.

However I assume you are a beginner like me, thus maybe prefer to prove it by definition. It is not difficult, you only need to repeat trick I have shown.

$$|(\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{2}{3}| \leq |(\frac{3 \cdot 4^n}{6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{2}{3}| \\
=\frac{2}{3} \cdot (3^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$$

Thus for any positive real number $\epsilon$, there is a positive integer $N=\max \{1, \lfloor \frac{\ln 3}{\ln (\frac{3\epsilon}{2}+1)} \rfloor \}$ such that when $n>N$, $$|(\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{2}{3}|<\epsilon.$$

That's what we want to prove.

**Edited**: So far I think the most nature way in this kind of approach is to notice the result here: [Prove the following limit $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (3^n+4^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} =4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419882/prove-the-following-limit-lim-n-to-infty-3n-4n1-n-4).

I think one can prove it without squeeze lemma.

So
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (2^n+3^n+4^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=4$$
And
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (5^n+6^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=6$$
Thus the original limit is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: In that first line, I fail to recognize how that $2^n/6^n$ against that exponent $1/n$ turned out to be $2/3$ Could you elaborate please?

Comment: But how do you know that $(\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq (\frac{3 \cdot 4^n}{6^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: @imranfat That was a mistake...fixed ;)

Comment: @Jxt921 $2^n+3^n+4^n \leq 3 \cdot 4^n$ and $5^n+6^n \geq 6^n$. But I guess you are not asking for this.... Let me think a bit more.

Comment: A less trick and more nature way updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more classical approach. Take the $ln$ on both sides to get: $\frac{1}{n}*ln\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n}$=$\frac{ln(2^n+3^n+4^n)-ln(5^n+6^n)}{n}$=$\frac{ln(2^n+3^n+4^n)}{n}-\frac{ln(5^n+6^n)}{n}$ With $n$ to infinity, we can apply L'Hospital's Rule: $\frac{2^nln2+3^nln3+4^nln4}{2^n+3^n+4^n}-\frac{5^nln5+6^nln6}{5^n+6^n}$ Dividing all terms in the first fraction by $4^n$ and the second fraction by $6^n$ and let $n$ go to infinity, we arrive at $ln4-ln6$ which is $ln\frac{2}{3}$ (please verify!) Since this is really the $ln$ of our limit, the actual limit is $2/3$