Find the trace of the matrix multiplied $n$ times

Let $A=[a_{ij}]_{n\times n}$ such that $a_{ij}=\dfrac{(-1)^i(2i^2+1)}{4j^4+1}$. Then, the value of $1+\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\text{Trace}(A^n))^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is ______

The trace of the matrix is the sum of diagonal elements. We need to find the trace of $A^n$, but I do not know how to approach it, as it is becoming cumbersome.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419882/prove-the-following-limit-lim-n-to-infty-3n-4n1-n-4. It seems to be related to this well known result in limits. However it requires the numbers involved to be positive.
